# ios using dispatch_group_t fro multiple async calls

Tags: ios, json, asynchronous

I'm trying to set up a dispatch_group so I can make multiple async calls, store the multiple returned data into an array and then process them once all the calls are completed. Here's my code for getting the JSON:

```
- (void) getJSONFromArrayOfURLS : (NSArray*) arrURLS {

//create dispatch group
dispatch_group_t jsonGroup = dispatch_group_create();

for(NSURL* thisURL in arrURLS) {

    //enter dispatch group
    dispatch_group_enter(jsonGroup);

    //make nsurlsession query here
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10;

    NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:thisURL completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {

            //hit the servers but they returned an error
            if (error) {

                NSString* strErrMsg;

                if (error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) {
                    strErrMsg = @"The connection to the servers was lost. ";
                } else {
                    strErrMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The server sent this error message: \n%@", error.localizedDescription];
                }


                UIAlertController* alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"There was an error connecting to the servers."
                                                      message: strErrMsg
                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {



                                           }
                                           ];

                [alertController addAction:okAction];

                [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

            //hit servers successfully
            } else {

                //deseriealize the return
                id JSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                [self.arrReturnedData addObject:JSONObject];

            }

        } else {

            //never hit the servers
            UIAlertController* alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"There was an error connecting to the servers."
                                                  message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The server replied with the following status:\n\n%i", (int)httpResponse.statusCode]
                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                       }
                                       ];

            [alertController addAction:okAction];

            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }

    }];

    [dataTask resume];

    dispatch_group_leave(jsonGroup);
}


dispatch_group_notify(jsonGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)  {

    NSLog(@"%@", self.arrReturnedData);

});

}
```

The problem I am running into is I can see the JSON data come in successfully, if I break point on this line:

```
[self.arrReturnedData addObject:JSONObject];
```

The array has one object in it (an NSDictionary) with the data I am expecting. However, further down, here:

```
dispatch_group_notify(jsonGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)  {

    NSLog(@"%@", self.arrReturnedData);

});
```

The array is empty. I am new to dispatch_groups but my understanding was that group_notify would be called once all the task entered into jsonGroup had completed. I am not resetting the array anywhere so my thought here is this is being called before the array is populated during the async process. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: you should leave group when you got response from ws, either fail or success leave group

Comment: Also, be careful as array access is not thread safe, so you will need to synchronise this in some way. You also need to dispatch presentation of the alert controllers on the main queue.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tips, back to the lab!

Comment: Mike Alter - make your comment into an answer and I will accept it. Just moved the dispatch_group_leave(jsonGroup); line into the NSURLSession block and it worked.